# ngRepeat:dupes - Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-tags-input

I am using ngTagsInput directive with auto-complete. Everything works fine if i dont have two tags with same "tag_token" property.

This is my response that i get:

```
{
"id": "100",
"create_date": "2016-02-01T18:33:39Z",
"tag_token": "Tag 1",
"parent_id": "1",
"parent_type": "FILE"
},
{
"id": "101",
"create_date": "2016-02-01T18:33:39Z",
"tag_token": "Tag 2",
"parent_id": "2",
"parent_type": "FILE"
},
{
"id": "102",
"create_date_tdt": "2016-02-01T18:33:39Z",
"tag_token": "Tag 2",
"parent_id": "3",
"parent_type": "FILE"
}
```

**VIEW**

```
                 <tags-input             
                    ng-model="searchQuery"
                    display-property="tag_token"
                    key-property="tag_token"
                    on-tag-adding="checkTag($tag)"
                    on-tag-removed="onTagRemoved($tag)"
                    replace-spaces-with-dashes="false"
                    add-from-autocomplete-only="true"
                >
                <auto-complete min-length="1" max-results-to-show="10" source="typeahead($query)"></auto-complete>
                </tags-input>
```

I am getting this error:

```
Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: item in suggestionList.items track by track(item), Duplicate key: Tag 2, Duplicate value: {"tag_token":"Tag 2"}
http://errors.angularjs......
    at angular.js:68
    at ngRepeatAction (angular.js:27518)
    at Object.$watchCollectionAction [as fn] (angular.js:15761)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:15896)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:16160)
    at done (angular.js:10589)
    at completeRequest (angular.js:10787)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.js:10728)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `key-property="id"`. Here is [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/yb0Mx5v977s83hml5vdJ?p=preview)

e.g.

```
<tags-input             
        ng-model="searchQuery"
        display-property="tag_token"
        key-property="id"
        replace-spaces-with-dashes="false"
        ...
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

On the tags input try `key-property="tag_token track by $index"`

Comment: Well i try this also... but no success again same error .... Duplicate value: {"tag_token track by $index":"Tag 2"}

Answer (score 0):

use `key-property="id" display-property="tag_token"`

**Syntax :**  if you have this type of json

```
 [
    {
     name:"Rohit", 
     id:"2"
    },
    {
     name:"Virat",
     id:"2"
    }
 ]
```

then use `key-property="id" display-property="name"`